# StackOverFlowError in onCreateView of MapFragment

Tags: android, stack-overflow, google-maps-android-api-2

```
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889): com.App.mobileapp fatal error : null
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.c.n.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.c.n.b(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.c.n.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.a.ae.d(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.a.bq.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.y.al.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.y.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.y.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.y.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.y.bu.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at maps.y.p.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d$4.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.App.mobileapp.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:19)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1160)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.App.mobileapp.maps.SearchViewOnMapActivity.onCreate(mMapActivity.java:67)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-18 17:17:58.929: E/ACRA(6889):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is the stacktrace**

at `setContentView(R.layout.map);` of the `mMapActivity`

and `MapFragment.java:19` is

```
View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

**Complete MapFragment.java**

```
public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return root;
    }
    }
```

**map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_searchViewOnMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/loadButton_searchViewOnMap"
    class="com.App.mobileapp.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that doesn't look good. Since your stack trace shows no sign of infinite recursion, you are just running out of stack space in normal execution. The main application thread has only 8KB of stack space, IIRC.

You are going to have to examine the stack and figure out where you can remove calls. For example, your above code does not need to override `onCreateView()`, since you are not doing anything there at present.

You might also consider posting this to [the Maps issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list), as the maps code seems more at fault for excessive stack consumption than does your code, so perhaps they can improve matters in the future.